# How keep original filename with JS - Express - Multer upload script?

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I use following script for uploading a single file, with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Upload works fine but original filename is lost in the process. Uploading a file named 'myfilename.pdf' results in uploaded file with name like 'file-1699291637638.pdf'.

What should I change to make sure the name of the uploaded file is the same as the original filename?

See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ruud00000/js-fileuploader/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0009356izyqaalx0%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0004356izkby9icg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0007356i3edvvtsj%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0008356iq4a0iilo%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clor03r9m0004356izkby9icg%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0004356izkby9icg%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clorfek69002p356had2jf1ph%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0003356i807rqx2f%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fuploads%252Ffile-1699290743249.xlsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clorfek69002p356had2jf1ph%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clor03r9m0008356iq4a0iilo%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0008356iq4a0iilo%2522%257D%252C%2522clor03r9m0007356i3edvvtsj%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0005356idfy3obx7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clon2mmi7000keff8hp8mfn6u%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0006356iqaxu4bsp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clon2nen6000meff84u7ic7gc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0007356i3edvvtsj%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clor03r9m0005356idfy3obx7%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) for code (run with 'node index').

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Set up a storage engine to define where files will be stored
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads/'); // Uploads will be stored in the 'uploads/' directory
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

// Create an upload instance with the defined storage engine
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Serve static files from the 'uploads/' directory
app.use(express.static('uploads'));

// Define a route for the file upload form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

// Handle file upload
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.send('File uploaded successfully');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Don't use `path.extname()` -- that just gets the extension, not the whole name.